# Formatting Phone Numbers in Non-US format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code that I'm trying to refactor to format a phone number field in the format I need it in:

```
STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE('02 212345678','02 2','02 '), 7, 0, ' '), 3, 0, ') '), 1, 0, '(')
```

It returns data currently as this:

```
(02)  123 45678
```

where I need it in this format

```
(02) 1234 5678
```

The problem is the extra space after the closing bracket and having 4 numbers either side.

Comment: It's not clear how you're intending to break the string up, use different digits instead of all 9 to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, does the following work for you?

```
with sampledata as (select '02 212345678' num)

select Concat(Stuff('() ',2,0,Left(num,2)), Stuff(Right(num,8),5,0,' '))
from sampledata
```

Comment: Cheers mate, works like a dream.

Comment: First STUFF() is sort of unnecessary. Could be shortened by just using CONCAT() to add the parentheses ```SELECT Concat('(',Left(num,2),') ',Stuff(Right(num,8),5,0,' '))```

Answer (score 0):

You existing code works, just need to change the 7 to an 8, but I far prefer to keep my formatting and data seperated. The code is waaaaaay easier to read and modify:

```
DECLARE @PhoneNumber varchar(20) = '02 212345678';

SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('(%s) %s %s', LEFT(@PhoneNumber, 2), SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, 4, 4), SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, 8, 4) );
```

Comment: While this is fine for ad-hoc or minimal row use, beware *formatmessage* is not performant and should be avoided on larger sets of rows, I've tested it before and found it to be up to 20x slower.

Comment: Adhoc queries for adhoc schema design. Formatting like this regardless of whether you use STUFF, CONCAT, FORMATMESSAGE, xp_sprintf is a bad idea to have in customer facing queries. Poorly formatted data = poor performing database queries. If a phone number has distinct parts that you need to work with individually, then they should be stored in individual columns. Validate and format your data before you save it to your database or the cost of doing that validation and formatting will need to be done on every row in every query forever after.